# How to access a class variable in a std::vector?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a vector consisting of a variation of classes, and I am trying to access a variable found in the classes. For example:

```
class MyClass1
{
public:
    int variable = 5;
};

std::vector<std::variant<MyClass1, MyClass2, MyClass3>> data;

data[0].emplace<MyClass2>();
...
data[5].emplace<MyClass1>(); // initialising 

std::cout << data[5].variable << std::endl;
```

Expected output:

```
5
```

Comment: do you know how to access something in a `std::variant` when it is not in a `vector` ?

Comment: Do `MyClass2` and `MyClass3` also contain a `variable` member?

Comment: As shown that code can't compile, much less produce any output. It looks like you are not familiar with accessing [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) active alternative *regardless* of whether they're in a container or not.

Comment: I am aware that you can use std::get to access data in a variant.

Comment: please post a [mcve] and the complete compiler error message. If you already know that you can use `std::get` why do you not use it?

Comment: your vector is empty, there is no element to be accessed

Comment: *"I am aware that you can use std::get to access data in a variant"* - And you're not doing so because... ?  Btw, what was the *actual* output? A compile-time error? That should be included verbatim with your interpretation of said-same,  along with your [mcve] requested earlier.

Comment: I have tried: `std::get<MyClass1>(data[5]).variable`, but with no success.

Comment: `data[0]` or any other index is out-of-bounds. Your vector has `0` elements, you need to add some before you can access them via `operator[]`

Comment: "I have tried: std::get<MyClass1>(data[5]).variable, but with no success." If you post a [mcve] where you try that and post the error message we can help